# Why this syntax allowed in const function

Tags: c++

```
class A {
public:
  void ConstFoo() const;
private:
  B* m_ptr;
}

void A::ConstFoo() const
{
  m_ptr->MutableFoo(true);
}

class B {
public:
  void MutableFoo(bool changed);
private:
  bool m_flag;
}

void B::MutableFoo(bool changed)
{
  m_flag = changed;
}
```

I expected this code to not be able to compile, But it isn't.

If class's member variable is pointer, It can call non-const function?

As I know, Const function can't call non-const function inside the body and cannot change member's state..

Could you explain why this code works?

Comment: "If class's member variable is pointer, It can call non-const function?" Yes, because that won't change the member variable - it will only change the *object that is pointed at*.

Comment: `const` member functions cannot change members of their `class`. But that doesn't mean they cannot change something *else* via a pointer. C++ implements "bitwise const", not "logical const". And then throw in `mutable` to further muddy the waters. In the end it all boils down to C++ having some mechanisms to help programmers *try to* not make mistakes, but if the programmer *insists*, then mistakes can usually be made.

Comment: `const` isn't transitive (alas, I wish it were).  If a `const` object has a `const` pointer to a `mutable` (non-const) object, that `const` pointer can be used to modify the `mutable` object.  (Most things are implicitly `mutable` unless explicitly declared `const`.)